# Command line bash variables in pipeline

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe

Is there are way to use STDIN in a bash function?

e.g.

```
# echo "somevar = (100)" >> test.txt
# grep -Eo "\([[:digit:]]+\)$" test.txt
(100)
```

So that's fine I've got my number, next I want to remove the brackets.
What I did was:

```
string=`grep -Eo "\([[:digit:]]+\)$" test.txt`; echo ${string:1:-1}
100
```

So my problem was solved, but what I spent a long time doing was:

```
grep -Eo "\([[:digit:]]+\)$" test.txt | echo ${$1:1:-1}
grep -Eo "\([[:digit:]]+\)$" test.txt | ${$1:1:-1}
grep -Eo "\([[:digit:]]+\)$" test.txt | xargs echo ${:1:-1}
grep -Eo "\([[:digit:]]+\)$" test.txt | xargs -I 's' echo ${s:1:-1}
```

etc, etc ... none of which work.

So assuming it is possible, how do I use the piped in value in the bash command?

Comment: It's not clear what you intend the syntax you're writing to do/mean.

Comment: ...that said, for a general discussion of reading an input stream for native use by shell, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- and [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for discussion of a common caveat.

Comment: I want know if I could achieve the same as the working example using a pipe rather than storing it in a variable. Though your links to the BashFAQ seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use some input from a pipe and that each line of input is to be processed separately, you could try:

```
echo "somevar = (100)" | grep -Eo "\([[:digit:]]+\)$" | while read in
do
  echo $in
done
```

The `while` loop will use the `read` command to read one line at a time in the variable `IN`. Within the loop you may do any treatment you need. In this case I have used an `echo` to show that you get the input value back.

Comment: This particular formulation is vulnerable to [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: (btw, all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph; thus, better to `while read line` -- or `while IFS= read -r line`, if you don't want to mangle backslashes or leading/trailing whitespace).

Comment: @Charles Duffy states that the `IN` variable will not be available outside of the loop, but it is good if used within. I have also changed it to lower case as suggested.

Comment: A little more verbose than I was hoping (secretly I thought a perl-esq $_ might exist in bash) but it does exactly what I was asking for, Thanks also to Charles Duffy, you clearly know your Bash!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using is for variables. Saving `grep`'s output in variable is the natural way to use it.

If you want to use a pipeline you need to use something that modifies stdin, rather than a variable. Consider `sed`.

```
grep -Eo "\([[:digit:]]+\)$" test.txt | sed 's/^(\|)$//g'
```